# Can't access the CKEDITOR Object after appending it dynamically

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

when i am appending the script that calls CKEDITOR I've encountered a problem. It loads the CKEDITOR on html view but when i try to use the CKEDITOR's objetc using javascript there is a problem cause I can't acces the this objetc. I've a problem when i try to use CKEDITOR.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");              

script.type = "text/javascript";

script.async = false;

script.src = pathToScript;

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); 

if(CKEDITOR.instances) {
   this.o_edit = CKEDITOR.instances[IdOfTextArea];
}
```

The CKEDITOR's instance isn't created.

Somebody can help ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(CKEDITOR.instances) {
        this.o_edit = CKEDITOR.instances[IdOfTextArea];
    }
}
```

In this case you make sure that all the scripts are loaded before you try to access the objects.

Update: if after getting the error in you initial script try to open the console and type CKEDITOR and see its value, it's 99% that it will be created by that time and evaluated correctly

Comment: Thanks bro, but it still doesn't  work. I put it on console and it's ok, but in the source i can't use the objetc CKEDITOR. The message is "undefined is not a function" when i try to use it.

Comment: @RenanSantos the message means you try to use a variable (which is supposed to be a function) as a function. In the code you provided (if the structure of your page is correct) I don't see any incorrect invocation (just because I pasted it to my notepad) so I guess your script fails at another steps, not at place you pasted here

Comment: var script = document.createElement("script");    
   
    script.type = "text/javascript";    

    script.async = false;

    script.src = "objs/ckeditor/ckeditor.js";

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    window.onload = function() { // it does'n enter here
        if(CKEDITOR.instances) {
            this.o_edit = CKEDITOR.instances[textAreaId];
        }
    }

    console.log(CKEDITOR);

The result is  "undefined"

Comment: @RenanSantos your "console.log(CKEDITOR)" is put outside of "window.onload". When I put my obj (analog of CKEDITOR) outside of "onload", JS also says it's undefined. Put it into window.onload and check again. When I was debugging the script, by the time when window.onload was fired, the object had been initialized.